# Sending HTTP request from Android app

Tags: android, http

Currently in cURL I can run a basic request like this:

```
curl -u username:token https://api.mywebsite.com -H "Accept: application/custom-header"
```

It authenticates, it picks up the custom header and everything is great.

However, I want to do this from an Android app. I had a look at `HttpClient` but it was deprecated at API level 22. So now I'm trying to find something else to do the job.

What is the current/best way to do this from an Android app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley Library of google for the Network call check this [Volley site](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)